# access outer “this” in Javascript sort method in prototype

Tags: javascript

I have following code

```
var Index = function( columns ) {
    this.columns = columns;
};

Index.prototype = {
    indexes: [],

    push: function( object ) {
        this.indexes.push(object);
    },

    compare: function( object1, object2 ) {
        var compareVal = -1;
        for( var i = 0; i < this.columns.length ; i++ ) {
            compareVal = object1[this.columns[i]].localeCompare(object2[this.columns[i]]);
            if( compareVal != 0 )
                return compareVal;
        }
        return compareVal;
    },

    rebuildIndexes : function() {
        this.indexes.sort(this.compare);
    },
};

var testIndex = new Index( [ 'type', 'name', 'id' ] );
testIndex.push({ "id": "123", "name": "Name 1", "type": "4" } );
testIndex.push({ "id": "34", "name": "Name 3", "type": "3" }  );
testIndex.push({ "id": "13", "name": "Name 2", "type": "2" }  );
testIndex.push({ "id": "73", "name": "Name 4", "type": "2" }  );
testIndex.rebuildIndexes();
var text = "";
for(var i=0; i<testIndex.indexes.length;i++) {
    text += testIndex.indexes[i]['type'] + ", ";
}
$('body').html(text);
```

But this code is not working. The compare function does not see **this** of the Index prototype, and says it is undefined. How can I access outer this in sort function in prototype.

Here is the [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/o7ury45n/).

Comment: Easy/dirty solution: `this.indexes.sort(this.compare.bind(this));`

Comment: You can always do the ol' `var self = this`, bind (if your target browser support it), or wrap the loop in a closure.

Comment: @Sirko thanx. It has worked.

Comment: Are you sure you want indexes on the prototype? If you create a new Index instance at the end you'll see that instance shares the indexes array with testIndex. var i2 = new Index; console.dir(t2.indexes); more info on prototype here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711